# Decimal with digits precision on scorecard

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to display a decimal on the scorecard. By default it goes for a whole number but i want 1 digit precision. E.g. instead of 99 display 92.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the source column, go to the Modeling -> Formatting
And set:
Data Type: Decimal Number
Format: Decimal Number
And in the dropdown below select the number of digits precision required.
[image]